# ES6 Promises run out of order when using Node-MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

Why does this series of promises run out of order? The "object" object in the final .then block is undefined at runtime.

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    getConnection().query("SELECT * FROM blog", (err, rows) => {
        if (err) reject(err)
        else resolve(rows)
    })

}).then(rows => {

    let posts = []

    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        posts.push({
            id:      rows[i].id,
            ...
        })
    }

    return posts

}).then(posts => {

    getConnection().query("SELECT * FROM shows", (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw new Error(err)
        else return { posts: posts, shows: rows }
    })

}).then(object => {

    let posts = object.posts

    let post_container = { my: [], your: [] }

    post_container.my   = posts.filter(x => x.section === "my")
    post_container.your = posts.filter(x => x.section === "your")

    return post_container

})
```

Comment: The second query is where it messes up. All variables are defined properly until `getConnection().query("SELECT * FROM shows"` If I were to put a log "here 1" in that query's callback, and then a "here 2" under `let posts = object.posts`, the here 2 consistently runs before here 1.

Comment: Side note: You might look at using `Array#map` in your code transforming `rows` into `posts`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `return` in

```
.then(posts => {

    getConnection().query("SELECT * FROM shows", (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw new Error(err)
        else return { posts: posts, shows: rows }
    })

})
```

...returns from the **`query` callback**, not the `then` callback; that return value is completely ignored. Since there's no explicit `return` in the `then` callback, it returns a promise resolved with `undefined` and so the following `then` callback is called with `undefined` (and before the async work above is done).

You need to return either a value to use immediately or a promise from the `then` callback; since your code in the `then` callback is asynchronous, you'll want to return a promise that you settle when the async work is complete, so:

```
.then(posts => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getConnection().query("SELECT * FROM shows", (err, rows) => {
            if (err) reject(/*...reject reason...*/)
            else resolve({ posts: posts, shows: rows })
        })
    })
})
```

---

You might look at one of the libs that promise-ifies NodeJS callbacks so you can use promises more directly in your code. There are at least a couple, and then you could use the promise a promise-ified `query` gave you rather than having to create your own each time.

Comment: The explanation "You need to return either a value to use immediately or a promise..." really makes things click a bit more about promises and how they work. Will accept answer when the time limit allows me to. Thank you.